# Slide up and Slide down Div - Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently working on Bootstrap 3 and making the HTML Markup but I don't know how to make this type of widget

> On click “Need help?” should slide down and hide and below div slide
>   up in it’s place ... When the cross is clicked popup should hide and
>   “Need help?” slide up again.

HTML Markup below

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 helpContainer no-gutter">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-gutter">
                                <a href="#" class="HelpButton">Need help? <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                            </div><!-- col-md-12 -->
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 no-gutter">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <a href="#" class="CloseButton"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                                </div><!-- col-md-12 -->
                                <p class="HelpPopup">Not sure which service offers the greatest return on investment for your company? <a href="#">We can help</a></p>
                            </div><!-- col-md-12 -->
                        </div><!-- col-md-12 -->
```

Please let me know how this is possible.

Here is the screenshot for better understanding

[Image Link](http://i57.tinypic.com/v4v685.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

If you're using bootstrap, why not use it's included Collapse functionality provided with the boostrap JavaScript files.

See here: [http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse)

Without seeing how you are trying to achieve this on the client side it's hard to make suggestions on just your HTML markup. For a quick and easy option, use the Bootstrap JS includes and add a few extra tags to let that do the binding for you :). If you need extra functionality such as hiding buttons when one is clicked that can be achieved quite easily in jQuery.

Comment: Please see the attached image. Collapse function is different what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Why is it different? The only thing I can see that is different is you want it to hide some elements. To do this you can actually write some simple jQuery for the click event, hide the elements and then invoke the collapse functionality.

Alternatively you can do it the opposite way, hide when the collapse method is invoked. I can amend my answer to show this but I'm sure you can achieve it by reading the Boostrap JS documentation.

Comment: It will be better for me if you can give me modified version of this function because If I started working on this then I can't complete the page today.